# The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found - Using API

Tags: c#, .net, api, httpwebrequest

I started using new API (appoxee).
When sending a request i got the "(404) Not Found".

This is the code i am using to send the request:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("http://saas.appoxee.com/api/") as HttpWebRequest;
request.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
request.ContentType = "application/json";

// Add the content to the request
string postDataJsonFormat = CreateExampleTagRequest();
byte[] byteArray = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postDataJsonFormat);
request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;

Stream dataStream = request.GetRequestStream();
dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);
dataStream.Close();

// Getting and processing the response
var response = request.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

I know this is the correct api url and cannot figure out what is the problem here.

Comment: The code seems to be correct. I'd say there's a temporary problem on Appoxee's side. If it persists, try contacting them directly.

Comment: Seems like that API URL indeed leads to a 404 not found. I'd recommend that you contact the vendor and let them know you are seeing this issue.

Comment: Thanks guys. I talked to them and now i am getting forward and getting internal server error 500 ):